# Simulating non-linear SDE in Matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I have this non-linear process that sort of looks like GBM, but is not because of the square-root noise. Both Mu's are constants, and l (in front of one Mu, and sigma) is a parameter. Sigma is a constant too. N is a population that increases.

[image: dynamic]

This is not easily solved analytically.

Ultimately, I'm interested in starting off a bunch of these guys in Matlab with "continous" time steps, vary the parameter l for each process, and see what that looks like.

Since I've never done anything with SDE's in Matlab, I am a little lost. I've had a look at the different SDE solvers, but I can't seem to make them work. As said, I'm not hoping to solve anything, just manipulate different population sizes, time, and this parameter l.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: That's not an ODE, but an [SDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_differential_equation). It looks like a form of [CIR process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox–Ingersoll–Ross_model). If you have Matlab's [Financial Toolbox](http://mathworks.com/help/finance/) you may be able to use [`cir`](http://mathworks.com/help/finance/cir.html) or manually specify your SDE. Otherwise, you can check out my [SDETools](https://github.com/horchler/SDETools) on Github.

Comment: Yes. It is close to a CIR process. However, I don't want the mean reversion part, so I need to specify something myself. I've downloaded your SDETools and installed it, but still somewhat at loss at how to actually do it. I will have a look at some of your examples. Thanks!

Comment: If you're not familiar with SDEs and Euler-Maruyma integration, I strongly suggest reading something like *[An Algorithmic Introduction to Numerical Simulation of Stochastic Differential Equations](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/S0036144500378302)* by Desmond J. Higham before proceeding. The paper features many Matlab examples (though some of the code is a bit outdated and certainly not optimized for performance). The URL to the Matlab files in the paper won't work, but they can be [found here](http://personal.strath.ac.uk/d.j.higham/algfiles.html).

Comment: That was very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Desmond J. Higham I ended up with this, sort of ugly looking approach. It's quite slow. If anyone had any suggestions as to how I would vectorize or include a SDE solver, such as SDETools to simulate it faster, I would be very grateful.

```
clear;
clc;

clf
T = 35; 
N = 2^12; 
Delta = T/N;           
lambda = 0.1; 
sigma = 4; 
Xzero = 1;  
P = 500;

Xem = zeros(1,N+1);    
Xem(1) = Xzero;

for i = 1:P
    for j = 1:N

        if log(Xem(j)) < 0
            Xem(j) = nan;
        end

        Winc = sqrt(Delta)*randn;
        Xem(j+1) = Xem(j) + lambda*Delta*Xem(j) + sigma*sqrt(Xem(j))*Winc;

    end
    plot(0:Delta:T,log(Xem))
    xlabel('t','FontSize',16), ylabel('X','FontSize',16)
    hold on;
end
```